# solved - contract to transfer multiple tokens

Tags: eosio.token, transfer, asset

I tried to create a function to transfer multiple tokens on one transaction.

code.

token.cpp

```
void token::transfers(const name &from,
                         const name &to,
                         const std::vector<asset> &quantities,
                         const string &memo)
   {
      for (unsigned int a = 0; a < sizeof(quantities); a = a + 1)
      {
         check(from != to, "cannot transfer to self");
         require_auth(from);
         check(is_account(to), "to account does not exist");
         auto sym = quantities[a].symbol.code();
         stats statstable(get_self(), sym.raw());
         const auto &st = statstable.get(sym.raw());

         require_recipient(from);
         require_recipient(to);

         check(quantities[a].is_valid(), "invalid quantity");
         check(quantities[a].amount > 0, "must transfer positive quantity");
         check(quantities[a].symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch");
         check(memo.size() <= 256, "memo has more than 256 bytes");

         auto payer = has_auth(to) ? to : from;

         sub_balance(from, quantities[a]);
         add_balance(to, quantities[a], payer);
      }
   }
```

token.hpp

```
[[eosio::action]] void transfers(const name &from,
                                       const name &to,
                                       const std::vector<asset> &quantities,
                                       const string &memo);
```

transaction

```
cleos -u https://testnet.wax.eosdetroit.io push transaction '{
  "delay_sec": 0,
  "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
  "actions": [
    {
      "account": "wallet1",
      "name": "transfers",
      "data": {
        "from": "wallet1",
        "to": "wallet2",
        "quantities": ["10.0000 TEST", "10.0000 TESTE"],
        "memo": "test mult transfers"
      },
      "authorization": [
        {
          "actor": "wallet1",
          "permission": "active"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

i get this error.

```
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
Error Details:
assertion failure with message: unable to find key
pending console output:
```

#### Fix:

I changed code of **sizeof(quantities)** to **quantities.size()**

```
for (unsigned int a = 0; a < quantities.size(); a = a + 1)
```

Comment: Please mark your question as solved if you found a solution to your problem.

Comment: I would like to combine tokens from a few accounts.bwhat command can i use?